# Does the Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer support preserve log?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I have been searching the Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer documentation for an option to preserve the log via the devTools API, just as if a user had checked the option on the Network tab, but it doesn't seem like it is exposed.  Does anybody know if this is possible? I'm using Puppeteer to automate filling in a form on a web app and it redirects to a new site at the end, but I would like the network log to be preserved.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "network log"? How you get "network log" without a redirect?

Comment: If it doesn't, I imagine you can just write the log to a file before you navigate to the new page, and then append each page's log to the file every time you navigate to different pages.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/) does not appear to support Preserve Log, as you stated, but you should be able to set the default behavior of Preserve Log in the [Chromium source code](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=preserveConsoleLog&sq=package:chromium&type=cs) to be active by default using the following method:

```
Common.moduleSetting('preserveConsoleLog').set(true);
```