# How do I enable Preserve Log via the Chrome DevTools Protocol (from within a Selenium automated test)?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

At my company, we're in the process of transitioning authentication providers between an on-premises solution and a cloud provider (SaaS) for scaling reasons. In the Non-Prod environments, we're currently running a 50/50 split for testing purposes, and it has led to some aberrant behavior, seemingly exclusive to automated tests. My gut feeling is that the session affinity token isn't being passed correctly on a fresh run. Automated tests start with a blank slate every time, but manual user testing is unaffected because the previous run gave them a session affinity token that carried over to the next test.

To prove what's *actually* happening, I have been asked to provide an HTTP Archive (HAR) file for analysis. Having captured a number of these already, the problem is that the log is erased between the Login Page and the Landing Page. The simple solution is to enable Preserve Log...

But, this problem doesn't happen every test run. Seemingly, it's about 20% of the time. As such, I don't want to have to manually observe 20+ test runs to get all variations of this specific problem.

Enter the Selenium v4 capability of Chrome DevTools Protocol. Ideally, I want to be able to [enable Network tracking](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-enable), but in that API reference I don't see any mention of [saving requests across page loads](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference#preserve-log). Presumably, everything that is in the UI is available through some flag, command, or API call, but I can't find any mention of this feature. The closest I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110970/how-to-enable-preserve-logs-in-chrome-remote-browser-using-selenium), but I'm not using Sauce Labs.

As I was about to submit the question, I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533560/does-the-chrome-devtools-protocol-viewer-support-preserve-log) StackOverflow question, but the answer seems like it might be conflating two different settings? I checked the references, but it's all links to the unit tests checking if Console messages are preserved, not Network events.

Comment: It's not exposed via CDP, it's a devtools frontend UI setting stored in `Preferences` file in the user profile as `devtools.synced_preferences_sync_disabled.preserveConsoleLog` and `devtools.preferences.network_log.preserve-log`. AFAICT you can set it via chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference()